# Как на JQuery выполнить функцию по клику на button ?

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня что то типа:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.ajaxbutton').click(
    function getajax(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/v1/post/?format=json',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(msg){
                alert("Ready")
            }})})
</script>
<div class="api">
    GET
<button class="ajaxbutton">ololo</button>
</div>
```

как переделать правильно?

Comment: хорошая статья о том, как правильно: [Step by step from jQuery to Backbone](https://github.com/kjbekkelund/writings/blob/master/published/understanding-backbone.md/)

Comment: @Spectre - не могу согласиться, с необходимостью использования Backbone, если человек толком не осознает что и зачем он делает, то никакой Backbone не поможет, а если понимает - он легко справится и без него. К тому-же - далеко не всегда модель, которую предлагает Backbone, хорошо вписывается.

Comment: про использования Backbone не было речи, в статье пошагово идёт объяснение того, как добиться аналогичной функциональности **без** него, и только потом **с** ним

Comment: пошагово от нубского кода, к более продвинутому, что тут может быть неясно?

>не всегда модель, которую предлагает Backbone, хорошо вписывается

кстате, пример, просто интересно

Comment: @Spectre - в чем выражается "продвинутость"?

Вам нужен пример? Так вот он вам - есть 1 обработчик 1ого ajax запроса, или вы и тут Backbone будете тянуть? :)

К тому-же, далеко не везде нужны модели, далеко не везде нужна клиентская шаблонизация, роутеры, да и вообще "MVC" ( в кавычках т.к. то, что предлагает Backbone - не совсем MVC, да и, ИМХО, за редкими исключением - на клиенте MVC не место )

Backbone идеально подходит в случае написания одно-страничных client-server приложений, но он, определенно, не предназначен для повсеместного использования.

Comment: @Spectre, еще раз повторюсь - тот, кто понимает что делает напишет грамотный код как с backbone, так и без него, а тот, кто не понимает - не напишет.

PS: ничего не имею против повсеместного использования underscore, но не backbone

Comment: >про использования Backbone не было речи

и после этого

>1 обработчик 1ого ajax запроса, или вы и тут Backbone будете тянуть?

я чего-то непонимаю, я ни разу не утверждал, что желательно или необходимо использовать Backbone, я привел в пример статью, в которой хорошо паказано разделение ответственности на клиенте, причём **пошагово** объясняется как этого добиться, в этом то и есть продвинутость кода. 

>Вам нужен пример?

я не правильно понял ваш коммент, конечно вы правы, backbone не всегда вписывается, но опять же я не агитировал его использовать

Comment: @Spectre - да, но вы акцентировали внимание на его модель, соответственно, если даже, это будет какой-то велосипед - его тоже будет что-то типа backbone ( пускай, даже, это не будет отдельный скрипт, но суть будет таже ).

В общем я к тому, что не стоит доводить код до абсурда, дабы не получилось что-то типа:


  ![ну lol же][1]
  [1]: http://bsk.kpgs.ru/2010/010810/original/1210m3.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function getajax(){ /*...*/ }
$(function() {
   $('.ajaxbutton').on('click', getajax);
})
```

PS: не допускайте в вашем коде записей вида `}})})`

Answer (score 2):

Надо

```
$(function() {
    $('.ajaxbutton').click(function() {
    ....
    });
});
```

--Имя функции тут неприменимо--

upd: вы устанавливаете обработчик во время загрузки страницы. В момент выполнения вашего скрипта кнопка ещё не существует. Оберните в $().

Comment: применимо, только если необходимо в этой функции вызвать её же повторно. но при этом она не должна быть доступна из другой части скрипта